# How to modify a database which can be only access with FlameRobin in phpmyadmin/MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, firebird, flamerobin

How to modify a database which can be only access with FlameRobin in phpmyadmin or in MySQL Workbench

eg. I can access the database in FlameRobin. but when I try to access the DB in phpmyadmin It takes awhile to load then

```
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: FlameRobin is a database administration tool for Firebird RDBMS. Workbench is a database administration tool for MySQL. These two technologies don't overlap.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-administration-of-firebird/ & https://github.com/mariuz/firebirdwebadmin

Answer (score 2):

You can't. PHPMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench are tools to access MySQL databases, they can't connect to a Firebird database. You will need to use a tool that supports Firebird (like FlameRobin).